# Confused about Meteor Cordova and databases

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am very new to Meteor and find myself struggling to fully grasp the Cordova mobile features of Meteor. When you have a database server side and a "mock" of the database client side with Meteor web apps, how do databases work in Meteor with Cordova applications?

Does every instance of my app have a local database only, or is Meteor syncing to an app wide shared database of my same Meteor code running on a server somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the latter. A cordova app is not much different from a normal meteor app. It just runs in a webview element rather than in a full-fledged browser. This means it can still use the same, synchronized client side database as you would in a regular web app. If you didn't need the server and synchronization then meteor would probably not be the right tool for your needs (as it does a lot more than what you'd need).

Comment: So it's the *minimongo* that runs on javascript, which runs in the webview, and that one syncs up with the server like any other web based meteor app?